# OS dependent C++ memory leaks?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos, memory-leaks

**CONTEXT**

I run `Valgrind` on my codebase under `Linux` for my cross-platform library. I am trying to see if this is enough or if I should run a dynamic code analysis on `Windows` and `Mac` too

**QUESTION**

If **my platform independent** C++ code is not leaking on `Linux` (according to `Valgrind`), can I assume it is not leaking on `Windows` and `Mac` too? If no, please provide a platform independent C++ sample not leaking on `Linux` (according to `Valgrind`) but leaking on `Windows` and/or `Mac` (choose "common" compilers like those in VC++, GCC, etc).

**Precision (thanks to comments and answers)**

1. I am interested in platform independent C++ code (so no #ifdef, etc);
2. I consider C++ code I own, not third party code;
3. I consider Valgrind as the ground-truth but I could consider any other tool. I know that no tool could detect all memory leaks.

Comment: If you have platform-dependent code or use platform-dependent third-party-libraries you should definitely run a valgrind analysis on `Windows` and `Mac` too. As even compilers are platform-dependent and can contain platform-dependent bugs -> run valgrind.

Comment: Indeed! I edited my question to focus on platform independent C++ code only.

Comment: I only consider MY C++ code. Not the one of third party library.

Comment: Oh, and don't forget implementation bugs which could trigger a leak in your C++ code, although that would just be bad luck.

Comment: @rubenvb: I don't "own" this code;)

Comment: @Korchkidu but you'll still have leaks nonetheless in that case... making it your problem.

Comment: @rubenvb: indeed, but if I do not own the code, my options are limited. I want to focus on my code first, then the others' code;)

Comment: @Korchkidu I guess my point is that there is no 100% sure way to know without actually checking at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can be pretty sure that generic code isn't leaking, but of course, if you have a decent size application, it is quite likely that SOME of your code is specific to Linux, other bits specific to Windows and some parts specific to OS X.

Those portions that are not specific to Linux will of course not be tested by Valgrind.

So if you have some piece of code that does:

```
#if LINUX
 char buffer[512]; 
#else
  char buffer = new buffer[2048]; 
#endif
  ... use buffer ...
```

then you have a memory leak in Windows but not Linux.

Clearly, this is a trivial example, but similar things can creep into code at times.

And of course, there is the potential that using a system call of some sort in the one OS is "safe" to not close or otherwise "tell the OS you are finished", and then have a problem in another OS.

Also, as I have pointed out before, Valgrind doesn't guarantee that you haven't got issue with memory usage - it only detects things like:

```
 void func()
 {
     char *p = new [1700];
     ... 
     // no free of p;
 }
```

or

```
 void func()
 {
     char *p = new [1700];
     ... 
     // No free. 
     p = some_other_pointer; 
     ... 
 }
```

but not:

```
 void func()
 {
    vector<int> v;
    for(;;)
       v.push_back(1); 
 }
```

because the memory is still "owned" by something. Of course, this particular example is quite extreme, but you can have similar things where the code is storing something and just adding more and more items to the storage, and never removing them.

Comment: I asked for platform independent code^^. See my edits. Also, I precised "according to Valgrind."

Answer (score 3):

**`valgrind` helps to find flaws, but does not guarantee correctness.**

You could still have undefined behaviour in your code, and that undefined behaviour could manifest itself differently on different platforms, including leaking memory on one but not the other.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I precised "according to Valgrind".

Answer (score 1):

If you have conditionally compiled code(e.g. `#if defined (OS_LINUX)`) then
you surely need to make sure that its leak free for each platform.

Note: This is not a complete answer but just a case I thought of.

Comment: Indeed, I did not think about that. C++ code sample is trivial in that context. I edited my question to focus on platform independent C++ code only.